# How to access an ODBC data source with PHP (Configuration)?

Tags: php, odbc, datasource

I have access to an ODBC datasource at work. It connects using MS Access currently; however, I need to be able to access these tables from a webserver in order to set up a simple webpage with charts for solar panel readings. Currently all my web code is working as long as MS Access is running on the webserver. Is there a way I can configure this connection to not need MS Access running in order to connect? I am on a windows server 2k12 setup.

Comment: check this: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.uodbc.php

Comment: I have no problems connecting to it and running queries with php. The problem is in how ODBC is configured on the server. MS Access has to be running in the background and logged into the datasource. It is obnoxious to have to reboot MS Access every day and seems like a waste of resources to have a program like that running on a server. I'm trying to cut out the middle man.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code to connect to my companies database, that seems to work quite well:

```
$server="Driver={Client Access ODBC Driver (32-bit)};System=DATABASEURL.COM;DBQ=DATABASENAME";

$user="USERNAME";
$pass="PASSWORD";

$conn=odbc_connect($server,$user,$pass);

#Check Connection
if ($conn == false) {
    echo "Not able to connect to database...<br>";
    exit;
}
```

Comment: I'm looking into trying this solution, I don't think the ODBC driver is configured correctly on the server currently. We have a tnsnames.ora file that sets up most of the datasource information, could that have something to do with why it requires MS Access?